# NGINX - Share same location body based on URL

Tags: nginx

In NGINX, I need to catch several URL's, and as a NGINX noob, not sure how to make this cleaner.  Any chance I can use one body block and catch all these urls ?

```
location ~ ^/wc-api {
         root /var/www/production/wordpress;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         }
    }

    location ~ ^/checkout {
         root /var/www/production/wordpress;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         }
    }

    location ~ ^/en/checkout {
         root /var/www/production/wordpress;
         index index.php index.html index.htm;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
         location ~ \.php$ {
              include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
              fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Try: `location ~ ^/(wc-api|checkout|en/checkout)`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (did not test first line regex, but syntax seems to be ok):

```
location ~ ^/(wc-api|(en/)?checkout) {
    root /var/www/production/wordpress;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```